# Find the two sets of points which have the minimum difference?

Tags: c#-4.0

Imagine we have set of V1= { p0(x0,y0), p1(x1,y1),p2(x2,y2),p3(x3,y3),p4(x4,y4)}

and set V2= { M0(x0,y0),.........Mn(xn,yn) }

The number of members in V1 is constant [ lets say 5 set of points }

Every time function minDifference() is called it should return set of points from V2 in which has the minimum difference with points in V1

in this example: output should return 5 set of points from V2 which has the least/minimum value difference with points in V1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<Point> V1 = new List<Point>();
V1.Add(new Point(2, 2));
V1.Add(new Point(4, 4));
V1.Add(new Point(6, 6));
V1.Add(new Point(8, 8));
V1.Add(new Point(10, 10));

List<Point> V2 = new List<Point>();
V2.Add(new Point(1, 1));
V2.Add(new Point(3, 3));
V2.Add(new Point(5, 5));
V2.Add(new Point(7, 7));
V2.Add(new Point(9, 9));

List<Point> result = new List<Point>();

foreach (Point p1 in V1)
{
    Point minPoint = Point.Empty;
    double minDist = double.MaxValue;
    foreach (Point p2 in V2)
    {
        double dist = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p1.X - p2.X, 2) + Math.Pow(p1.Y - p2.Y, 2));
        if (dist < minDist)
        {
            minDist = dist;
            minPoint = p2;
        }
    }
    result.Add(minPoint);
}
```

As an extra optimization, you can drop the `Math.Sqrt` since you don't really need the exact distance.

Comment: Thanks,this is a great approach,
But the problem is the number of points in V2 is much more than number of points in V1.
For example) no of points in V1 = { 5 } ; no of points in V2 = { 15 } 
 and we want to extract 5 set of points from V2 in which has the least difference with set points in V1

Comment: My solution also works if you have a lot more points in V2 than in V1. Try it.